# Facebook app redirecting to different subdomains

Tags: facebook, redirect, oauth

We're integrating facebook in our platform; we serve different customers and each one has a different access URL: http://customer1.example.com; http://customer2.example.com and so on. We're implementing OAuth 2.0 so customers are able to perform certain facebook actions from within the app.

From the looks of the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), it seems that we'll need one facebook app per customer, to make the authorization flow work. Is there a way to specify a "wildcard" Site URL, let's say: http://*.example.com ?

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE 3/19/2014** - there have been complaints that this functionality has been disabled.

---

The tooltip text next to the *App Domains* setting in the [facebook settings page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) **explicitly states that this is possible**:

> Enable auth on domain and subdomain(s) (e.g., "example.com" will enable *.example.com)

Comment: This doesn't work.  I tried with `http://domain.com` and `domain.com` and either times it doesn't work correctly

Answer (score -1):

No. You need a fixed URL. If you want to segregate the customers, then I would put a callback URL which can redirect the user correctly.

So, you have the callback URL as "http://callback.example.com". The app at callback.example.com, looks up the customer who is logged in and redirects them to the appropriate URL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. We might do that, the bad thing is that the URL for our App in Facebook will be callback.example.com. Cheers