# Is there a way to allow login with a single Facebook app on multiple subdomains?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to build a "RSVP to this event" action using the Facebook JS SDK.

All of our sites run on multiple subdomains (`event1.example.com`, `event2.example.com`) and I'm trying to setup a single Facebook app that will allow people to RSVP.

Ideally I'd like to be able to specify wildcard subdomains in the `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` settings, but Facebook doesn't seem to allow that.

Previous StackOverflow answers said that either just putting in the top-level domain or leaving that field blank would work ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666161/facebook-app-redirecting-to-different-subdomains)), but I always get the `This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings` error.

Frustratingly, we shouldn't need any sort of redirect callback to the server.  I just want a short-lived token to post the event RSVP which should be possible client-side only.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

The options I can think of...

**One app per subdomain** We have 100s of subdomains, so creating Facebook apps for each isn't going to work (plus that's a manual process)

**List all subdomains as redirect URIs** it appears [Facebook has a limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999831/facebook-login-from-subdomains-too-many-valid-oauth-redirect-uris) on the number of redirect URIs, plus this is also a manual process - there's no API endpoint for adding these

**Set the redirect URI via JS to our root domain** and then just ignore the callback - this seemed promising, but calling `FB.login` with a `redirect_uri` param gave an error: `When using FB.ui, you should not specify a redirect_uri.` Is there a way to do this without `FB.login`?

**Somehow let Facebook know we don't care about those redirects at all** -- is there some other way to request permissions and make a JS API call without needing the oauth redirect?

Thanks in advance for any insights...

Comment: I don’t see how you read out of the linked question that there was a limit. // Your options are to either add a redirect URI for every single sub domain; or handle login on the “main” domain, and redirect users back to the appropriate subdomain afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe you're right, I must have misread that.  In that case, it appears adding redirect URIs has to be a manual process (vs adding them via an API), which isn't really tenable when we're creating them on the fly.

Do you know a redirect is even necessary for a pure JS flow?  I don't need their tokens to hit my server at all.

Comment: No, for the client-side login flow that should not be necessary, I think. Set the base domain as app domain, and the base HTTP URL for the website platform, then it should work on subdomains.

Comment: Somehow I got this to work today.  I had to create a new app in the end and just completely ignored the oauth settings.  Miraculously it seems to be working now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: implement single sign on simple!.

Comment: @TouqeerShafi I don't think I follow...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that there is a way you can login through Facebook on multiple domains, but there is a proper work-around to implement sign-in on multiple domains it's called Single Sign On:

See:

https://www.sitepoint.com/single-sign-on-explained/

https://github.com/cubiclesoft/sso-server

Answer (score 0):

We could use **one specific sub domain/main domain itself** to handle the facebook authentication

Every time pass the `state` which includes `subdomain redirect uri` so that need not to adding sub domains to redirect uri list

Comment: I thought of maybe doing that in a small iframe since the actual RSVP button is embedded in the middle of a big page.  Thankfully re-creating the app without oauth seemed to work.